# Does anyone recognize this uniform?

Tags: military, identification, uniform, photography

I think it may be a Polish uniform, but I'm not sure. The eagle hanging down from the chest pocket seems unique in my web surfing for similar uniforms My family came to US from Snietnica, Galicia in 1907. So either it's a uniform prior to 1907 or it's another family member who remained in Eastern Europe. I would love to know a time range for this style uniform. 
[image]

Comment: The cap seems to be characteristically Polish Rogatywka . The collar markings seem like those discussed in https://polishforums.com/history/military-uniforms-collar-markings-64704/

Comment: @kimchilover True to cap & [collar](https://polanddaily.com/39-merian-c-cooper-creator-of-king-kong-and-one-of-the-fathers-of-the-polish-air-force), but the decoration seems typical [Polish eagle](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_Odrodzenia_Polski), & yet 'worn like a typical bookmark'?

Comment: Can you make out the lettering on the bottom of the eagle badge?

Comment: I can't make out the lettering under the eagle.  Any idea when this uniform was from?

Comment: Can you provide a higher resolution scan of the cap and the decoration on the breast?

Comment: "Czołgi" is Polish for "tanks".

Comment: @Spencer are you sure it says "Czołgi"? It looks more like a "Czoło" (literally "forehead") to me, which means has a meaning akin to"leader" or "front"/"vanguard"

Comment: @Yasskier The fifth letter has a different shape from the third one, and the stroke on the right is thicker than the ribbon's border, so I interpret it to be the letter "I".

Answer (score 4):

This is a placeholder for an answer.  This is definitely
a Polish uniform.  The cap shape and collar decoration are distinctively Polish.  The cut of the uniform looks World War I-ish.  I don't think the Sam Browne belt was much used outside Britain until about 1910, and became extremely widespread after World War I.

The Wikipedia article on Sam Browne belts has a [photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Browne_belt#/media/File:Mieczys%C5%82aw_Cieniuch_O1813499756.jpg)   of a modern Polish officer wearing the same kind of cap as your relative, with a zig-zag decoration on his cap related to the wiggly collar decoration on your photo (as discussed [here](https://polishforums.com/history/military-uniforms-collar-markings-64704/); that discussion cites [this](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barwy_broni_i_s%C5%82u%C5%BCb_Wojska_Polskiego_II_RP)), and of course sporting a Sam Browne.
The first two of these three things are definitely Polish.

Since Poland was not an independent country in the period 1795-1918, without an army of its own, it is unlikely your photograph dates from before 1918.  I believe during World War I there was a [Polish Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Legions_in_World_War_I) fighting with the Germans against Russia and a [Blue Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Army_(Poland)) fighting with the Allies against the Germans.  After the war veterans of the Blue Army wore a uniform similar to [yours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Army_(Poland)#/media/File:Polish_American_vets_of_World_War_I.jpg), even though during the war itself the Blue Army uniforms did not look like yours.

If the writing on the breast-pocket badge says "Czołgi" [="tanks"] as Spencer commented, the likelihood is that this was a Polish uniform of the period 1918-1939.
The Polish Army  made extensive use of tanks throughout the interwar period, as described in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanks_of_the_Polish_Armoured_Forces#Inter_War).

Comment: Have you ever seen such a uniform with national Polish symbols etc pre'18? Your Legions-link pretty much denies that as well.

Comment: No, but I could imagine a student club  or patriotic club might have.